# Box Topology/Sequences

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$. Make t a topological space using the box topology. Let $\pi_{n}$ denote the usual projection maps.

Fix $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and define $A_N = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$ $|$ $\pi_{k}(x) = 0$ $\forall k>N\}$. Show that $A_N$ is closed in the box topology.

We know that $A_N$ is closed in the box topology if it has a complement that is open in the box topology.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Just show that each $x\in\Bbb R^\omega\setminus A_N$ has an open nbhd that is disjoint from $A_N$. This is very straightforward: if $x\notin A_N$, there is a $k>N$ such that ... what?

Comment: $\pi_{k}(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Exactly, and from that it’s easy to identify an open nbhd of $x$ that’s disjoint from $A_N$.

Comment: So is it sufficient to say that an open neighborhood U that contains such an x is disjoint if x does not have any 0's in it.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Be careful: there are points of $\Bbb R^\omega\setminus A_N$ that **do** have some zero coordinates; in fact, every coordinate but one could be $0$. But as long as $x_k\ne 0$ for some $k>N$, you can specify an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A_N$. In fact, you can even specify an open nbhd of $x$ that is open in the ordinary product topology: $A_N$ is closed in the product topology as well as in the box topology.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $y\notin A_N$, then for some $k>N$ we have $\pi_k(y)=r\ne0$. Can you find a box around $y$ which does not intersect $A_N$. Think about what it means for a box $B$ to be disjoint from $A_N$.

Comment: Is it disjoint if x does not contain any 0's in it?

Comment: You have to say something about the elements in $B$ to express that $B$ is disjoint from $A_N$.

Comment: For all elements in B, as long as one coordinate is not 0, then B is disjoint from $A_N$. Does that work?

Comment: What is the restriction on this coordinate? If it's just the first coordinate and all the other coordinates are $0$, is this $x$ then really not in $A_N$?

Comment: Isn't x not in $A_N$ as long as $x_{k} \neq 0$ for some $k>N$?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Yes that's right.